# react-navigation stack navigation without initial screen? (from a button)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

We are using a different router for our app (react-router)

We are integrating react-navigation in some screens of our app.
(For example, we can adapt react-navigation for user profiles related screens)

Now, we have new requirements, where we want to use react-navigation from a button of an existing screen (which is not part of react-navigation)

Say you have a screen where there is a button which will create a new screen (stack a new screen). I want the navigation from the existing screen to new screen handled via react-navigation.

Comment: So you want to use two types of navigation frameworks in the app ?